# Page selection and identification

Tags: html, css

```css
#bannercontainer{
 height: 200;
 width: 960;
}
#banner1{
 height: 100px;
 width: 960px;
 background-color: white;
}
#banner2 {background-color: #4D4C4C;
 color: white;
 height: 100px;
 width: 960px;
 position: static;
}
.logo {
 width: 433px;
 height: 199px;
 float: left;
}
.linkcontainer{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
}
a:active{ color: grey;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: white;
 
}
a, a:visited { color: white;
 text-decoration: none; 
}


#link {
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-size:15pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 
  }
.selector { 
 background-color: white;
 color: #4D4C4C;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannercontainer">
 <div id="banner1">
 <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/Dulwich Design Banner.png" width="434" height="200" alt=""></a></div>
 </div>
 <div id="banner2">
  <div id="link"><div id="selector"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div></div>
 <div id="link"><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
 <div id="link"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></div>
 <div id="link">Contact</div><div id="link"> Projects</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So, while a user is on a given page, I would like the link to be white and the "selector" class to have a white background and grey text, essentially for the colours to be reversed while the page is active. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So - what is the question?  What problem do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it's not working it's because your element is using `id` instead of `class` for `selector`

So from this:

```
<div id="link">
   <div id="selector">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Change it to this:

```
<div id="link">
 <div class="selector">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And your css, update your `.selector` and add `.selector a` for the text color:

```
.selector { 
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.selector a {
  color: #4D4C4C;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdpnrL7x/)

Also note that it's not good to have the same `id` on multiple elements, you should use `class` instead. I'm referring to multiple elements with `links` id.